# What's wrong with this program? Why I getting runtime error in my following python code?

Tags: python

Recently, I started to solve a problem with UVA online judge. But after submitting this program it shows the following message: 'runtime error'.

```
v = int(input().split())
t = int(input().split())
d = v * (2*t)
if (v >= -100 and v <= 100) and (t >= 0 and t <= 200):
    print(str(d))
```

I tried this code too. But the result is same.

```
v = int(input())
t = int(input())
d = v * (2*t)
if (v >= -100 and v <= 100) and (t >= 0 and t <= 200):
    print(str(d))
```

Message:

UVa Online Judge 
12:40 AM (33 minutes ago)
to me

Hi,

This is an automated response from UVa Online Judge.

Your submission with number 24507447 for the problem 10071 - Back to High School Physics has received the verdict Runtime Error.

This means that the execution of your program didn't finish properly. Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0.

Best regards,

The UVa Online Judge team

Comment: `.split()` returns a list, which can't be converted to an int

Comment: Can you describe what are you trying to achieve here? Since split() will return list . Why are you splitting your input twice with different variables? A clear problem statement would be much appreciated.

Comment: at first, I tried without .split(). I tried with only the input() function. but the result was the same.

Comment: `Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0.` - have you tried adding `import sys; sys.exit(0)`?

Comment: no. I didn't try it. I am going to try it now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why `.split()` is needed in this example. The program seems to work fine without it

```py
v = int(input())
t = int(input())
d = v * (2*t)
if (v >= -100 and v <= 100) and (t >= 0 and t <= 200):
    print(str(d))
```

Edit: The final print statement can also just be `print(d)`, there is no reason to convert it to a string